# What's different with closing a window using Windows 7's taskbar preview?

Tags: windows-7

We have a windows app, written several years ago and maintained over time. We do not have any specific code to handle any Windows 7 UI features. Just plain old Winforms and WPF. We are seeing issues with closing windows using the Taskbar's preview and close button.
On some workstations, when the window is re-opened (calling the same tool via a menu), it is empty (white/blank). On other workstations, the same window is drawn outside the screen.

While there might be some custom code to initialize the window and restore it in the right location, what is troubling us is that none of those issues exist if we close the window using the standard close button on the title bar or using a "close" command.

Does anybody have any idea what is different between the closing of a window using the Taskbar and the standard button?

Regards,

Eric.